# Copying Data from a dynamic URL to SQL DW

Tags: azure-data-factory, sql-data-warehouse

I am copying data from a JSON script into my SQLDW. I am using the Copy Activity from DF2 where my datasets are HTTP-Source and  SQLDW-Target

Everything is working fine until I set up a URL parameter for my HTTP LinkedService connection and then I want to feed it with a LookUp Activity.

Is it possible to parameterize LinkedServices?

Comment: please show us the code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ‘Linked Service parameterization’ feature is currently under preview.